# Can't open application with Maven and JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-plugin

I am trying to convert my Java project to a Maven project, but after that I can't open my application using javaFX. H have tried adding different libraries. The application opened until I made it a Maven project. I think the problem is in the MainView. Please help!

My MainView:

```
package view;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;


public class MainView extends Application implements Interface{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml")));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>program</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>16</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>view.MainView</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the issue..
Dont actually understand what that means and don't found any answers anywhere..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at view.MainView.start(MainView.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Use one of the workflows from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ to create a `JavaFX` project. From there,  integrate the old code into the new project.

Comment: `getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml")` is returning null, causing the call to `Objects#requireNonNull(...)` to throw an NPE. When `getResource` returns null, that means the resource could not be found at the location specified. See the duplicate for information on how to figure out the correct resource path. Note that Maven, by default, expects resources to be under `src/main/resources` (whereas Java source files are expected to be under `src/main/java`).